# Disregard the year when using an IF formula with dates

Tags: excel

I want to use a *formula* to put the value "*Yes*" in a cell *X* if the *date* from cell *Y* is later than or equal to the *17th of January* (any year), or if the date from cell *Z* is earlier than the *17th of January* (any year).

This is what I've tried (apart from the date conditions, there are some others, but I've managed to figure those out):

```
=IF(OR(L4="Manually Integrated", L4="Integrated", I4>=DATE(****,1,17), I5<=Date(****,1,17)), "Yes", "No")
```

Basically I've tried to use wildcards to substitute the year, similar to using "*" or `LIKE` in SQL, but I can't get it to work. Is there a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```
=IF((DAY(I4)>16)+(MONTH(I5)<2)*(DAY(I5)<17),"Yes","No")
```

Comment: @Dreamwatcher I updated this due to a misreading of your requirement. It works well.

Answer (score 0):

Try `=if(or(or(month(y)>1,day(y)>16),and(month(z)=1,day(z)<17)),"yes","no")` . Replace y and z as necessary.